# Самообучение. Как самому изучить веб-программирование?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу стать веб-разрабочиком. Начала с изучения языков разметки: HTML/CSS. В интернете много информации, слишком много. На данный момент пытаюсь верстать по бесплатным макетам, но выходит не очень гладко, долго. Где лучше всего искать информацию? Сколько времени ушло у вас на изучение HTML/CSS?

Comment: начните с htmlacademy.ru - главное, не жадьтесь на платные уроки, потому что там всё самое нужное

Answer (score 2):

Времени уйдёт - вся жизнь. Это - константа. Причём не зависит от выбранной профессии. Вы идёте правильным путём. Пишите код, лечите ошибки. В качестве вводного мануала - выберите любой на ваш вкус, например [html5book](https://html5book.ru/). В качестве справочников советую W3CScools: [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/), [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/).

Comment: Я бы, наоборот, посоветовал держаться подальше от W3C. У меня опыт работы с ней был абсолютно отрицательный, так как статьи про элементарные вещи там могут быть неполными или ещё хуже - неверными. На англоязычном Stack я получал чаще всего куда больше полезной информации. И, кстати, там тоже W3С не любят.

Comment: Ну, я как правило ищу гуглом и чаще всего оно приводит меня именно на w3c или htmlbook. ЧСХ, помогает и сбоев такого подхода ещё не было :)

Comment: htmlbook да, прекрасный ресурс, вот его советую всем :)

Он и удобнее и понятнее w3c

Answer (score 1):

Cоветую начать изучение верстки с интерактивных курсов на htmlacademy.ru, там вполне неплохие уроки для новичков, которые закрепят на практике некоторые моменты. Затем можно JS заняться (начать с работы с DOM, т.к. верстать вы уже будете уметь), посмотреть learn.javascript.ru, обязательно много практиковаться, придумывая себе задачи по мере освоения нового материала, главное плавно к этому подойти, т.е. когда уже будете уверенно верстать и потребуется необходимость в какой-то интерактивности, иначе есть риск просто нахвататься инфы которую вы не будете знать где применить и выхлоп будет нулевой. Затем обязательно почитать какой-нибудь талмуд по JS, например Д.Фленаган, чтобы уже на основе имеющегося опыта в JS более углубленно понять как он работает. Это так, для начала. HTML/CSS - это капля в море, самое простое что может быть, на их изучение много времени не нужно.